# Android Emulator Logging Via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, android, typescript, ionic-framework, android-emulator

I am running an Ionic app integrated with SalesForce Mobile SDK. I am running it in Android Studio, because Ionic Serve doesn't support the SDK and some of the other plugins, and I need to run it in an Emulator. In this case - Android emulator.

I am new to Android Studio, can somebody guide me on how to put logs into the JavaScript/TypeScript code and view it in log (Logcat? Or anywhere else). I just want to understand the debugging and logging mechanism here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anything that is written to the browser's debugging console should be displayed in the Android logs, e.g. `console.log('Hello log!')` or `console.error('Is broke!')`

See [Console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console) for more info on using the console.

Comment: Thank you so much. The console logs show up as   "D/SystemWebChromeClient: file:///android_asset/www/build/main.js: Line 81 : Test"

Comment: Yeah it's super handy for debugging issues, sounds like you are going to have troubles with the SalesForce Mobile SDK if it doesn't support Ionic, does it support Cordova at least?

Comment: Yes it does support Cordova, so that helps!